# Convert chat symbols to emoji or text

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program to detect emoji and convert it into text. I am able to convert emojis like " " to text using the emoji library. But if I have symbols like ":-)" or ":D" in my text, how to detect & convert that into equivalent emoji(the actual picture) or text.

My Code is:

```py
import emoji
def check_for_emoji(text):
    split_text=text.split()
    for i in split_text:
        if i in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
            print("This is emoji:",i)
            print("The emoji means:",emoji.demojize(i))

text="Have a nice day  :)"
check_for_emoji(text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
This is emoji: 
The emoji means: :thumbs_up:
```

Now my code detects only the  but not ":)" this symbol. What should I do so that my code detects ":)" as well.

Comment: Hi Chhandosee Bhattacharya, welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see what you did first to be able to tell you what doesn't work with your code. I would suggest that you look at [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maximize the likelihood of having your question answered.

Comment: Hey EvensF, I have updated the question. Can you please check now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to do what you want to do. First of all, you have to decide which character combination you want to recognize in addition to those the `emoji` module does. Then you can search for each of these.

Here's one way to do this:

```py
import emoji

translation_emoticons = {
    ":-)" : u':smile:',
    ":D" : u':grinning:',
    ":)" : u':smile:',
    ":-(" : u':frowning_face:',
    ":-P" : u':stuck_out_tongue:'
}

translation_total = dict(emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)
translation_total.update(translation_emoticons)

def check_for_emoji(text):
    emoji_found = ((key, value) for (key, value) in translation_total.items()
                   if key in text)
    for (original, converted) in emoji_found:
        print("This is emoji:", original)
        print("The emoji means:", converted)

text = "Have a nice day  :)"
check_for_emoji(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking whether the emoji is in the list of unicode emojis (as defined in the emoji package you are using). `if i in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:`

The emoji `:)` is not in this list (in fact `:)` is not a unicode emojoi as far as I know).

So the list of emojis you are checking against does not include emojis such as `:)`. To detect such emojis, you could write custom code to do so.

PS: You could try printing the list of unicode emojis to see which are supported:

```
import  emoji
print(emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)
```